# Usando metodo via mapAction dentro do setup em Vue3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Estou utilizando o vue3 em um projeto para estudos e sigo com uma dúvida na utilização do método "setup", pelo que entendi ele é o metodo "global" do meu component, substituindo os metodos de methods, mmounted e etc, certo?

Pois, bem..

Atualmente tenho esse código:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
import Banner from './components/Banner.vue';

export default defineComponent({
   components: {
      Banner,
   },
   setup() {
      //not works
      this.loading(true);

      return{
         ...mapActions('Site', ['loading'])
      }
   },
})
</script>
```

Estou tentando acessar "this.loading", anteriormente quando eu usava o Vue2, eu definia o mapAction dentro de Methods, e em seguida dentro do mounted conseguia chamar a função, porém, agora com o vue3 nao consigo.

O que eu estou fazendo errado? Ou qual a melhor forma para usar?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'ref', é uma novidade no sistema reativo do Vue 3.

```
<script>
    import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
    import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
    import Banner from './components/Banner.vue';
     
    export default defineComponent({
       components: {
          Banner,
       },
       setup() {
        const loading = ref(true)
        //loading.value = false (etc...)
    
          return{
             ...mapActions('Site', ['loading'])
          }
       },
    })
    </script>
```